# sending seek event gstreamer pipeline

Tags: events, gstreamer, pipeline

Pipeline is constructed with source demuxer audio and video sinks. if a seek event is send to pipeline which have multiple sink pads then the order of sending the event to sinkpads can be decided by whom ? 
gst_element_send_event(pipeline, event)

as gst_element_send_event is synchronous call and if both pads are able to handle the seek event , then from where (audio/video sink) does it will get return status ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the problem is, but here are some bits'n'pieces:

- elements handle events, not pads (pads are just the point where the event come in)
- in your case the demuxer will handle seeks in time and convert them to seeks in bytes which it forwards
- the source, e.g. filesrc executes the seek in bytes